# I don't understand why I'm getting a C4700 error

Tags: compiler-errors

a. Tell the user that the program uses data from NASA to predict sea level from the years 2020 to 2050.
b. Store the sea level data in an array. You only need to use one data point for each year from 1993 to the present year. Use the last column for each row (the Global Mean Sea Level GMSL with annual and semi-annual signal removed).
c. Find the average annual change in sea level over all the years specified in the data. (Hint - use a loop to store the annual change in an array over the years, and then use a loop to compute the average annual change).
d. Assume a linear increase and compute the predicted sea level rise for the years 2020, 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, and 2050. Store these results in their own array. (Hint - just use the average you computed in part c as the annual change for the future years).
e. Display the results for the user and be sure to reference the data set as specified in the data file so the user knows where the data came from.

Please help me understand as to why I keep getting an C4700 error
   I've rewritten the code a few times and keep getting the same error and I     can't seem to figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define YEARS 26



int main() {



    double seaLevelp[26] = { 13.15, 13.29, 14.17, 13.93, 14.28, 14.62, 14.07, 14.94, 15.01, 15.67, 15.94, 16.18, 16.95, 17.12, 16.83, 17.30, 17.65, 18.17, 17.80, 18.69, 19.40, 19.50, 20.08, 21.39, 20.97, 21.36 };

    double seaLevelf[YEARS - 1];

    double average = 0.0, sum;



    for (int i = 0; i < YEARS - 1; i++) {

        seaLevelf[i] = seaLevelp[i + 1] - seaLevelp[i];


        double average; 0.0; sum; seaLevelf[i];


    }



    average = sum; {}(YEARS - 1);



    printf("   The Predicted Global Mean Sea Level is: nn");

    printf("        2020   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 2));

    printf("        2025   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 7));

    printf("        2030   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 12));

    printf("        2035   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 17));

    printf("        2040   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 22));

    printf("        2045   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 27));

    printf("        2050   %.2lf cm nn", seaLevelp[25] + (average * 32));

    printf("These predictions were made using data provided by:n      [https://www.sealevels.org/nnn]");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probably worth adding a tag saying what language this is... Also please provide a [mcve] that other people can actually run.

Comment: Not likely to be a valid syntax with all these ;

Comment: So it's C. I have no idea what this line is trying to do: `double average; 0.0; sum; seaLevelf[i];`, but it's invalid C.